# Run Event Macro After Data Validation Selection

Tags: vba, excel, events

I built up a data validation list on the sheet called report, I need to run a macro each time I select an item from the list. Now that I have this code below, but it doesn't work. It does run in VBA, but it will not run when I choose the Item in my worksheet, it seems like I didn't refer to the macros

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(True, True) = "$B$3" Then
        Select Case Target
             Case "ABCP"
                Call Macro1
             Case "Accounting Policy"
                Call Macro2
             Case Else
                  'Do Nothing
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` sub is called everytime you select a Range in your Worksheet. Your Selected Range gets passed as the `Target` parameter in the sub. Your code inside the `If` statement will only be executed if you selected the "$B$3" Cell.

Comment: What if I use Worksheet_Change?

Comment: Worksheet.Change gets called everytime a cell value changes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run the procedure when you have changed the value in B3 (picking from the data validation list, then you want a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro, not a Worksheet_SelectionChange.

Additionally, if anything on the worksheet is going to change then you will want to disable events so the event macro does not attempt to run on top of itself.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Select Case Target.Value2
             Case "ABCP"
                Call Macro1
             Case "Accounting Policy"
                Call Macro2
             Case Else
                  'Do Nothing
        End Select
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This should launch the correct sub procedure when B3 has a new value selected from the list. You would have to provide more details (and code) for m Macro1 and Macro2 if it continues to be problematic.

Comment: Thank you for answer so quickly. Just one silly question, should I put this code after the macro codes in module, or should I put it in worksheet?

Comment: An event macro like Worksheet_Change only operates from the worksheet code sheet not a module code sheet. Right-click the name tab of the worksheet and choose View Code. When the VBE opens, paste into the worksheet titled something like **Book1 - Sheet1 (Code)**.

Comment: I feel it is so close now, but why is it asking me to select macro after I run it?

Comment: I have never seen VBA ask me anything unless I specifically coded for that. Check your code.

Comment: @Jeeped My macro doesn't fireup (I've placed the code in module2), any idea why?

Comment: @singhswat - it needs to go into the worksheet's code sheet. Right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose View Code. You should be taken to the worksheet's code sheet (named something like Book1 - Sheet1 (Code))

Answer (score 1):

The above code appears to work fine for me.

Have you placed the code in the worksheet code? as opposed to a Module?

[image]